# "Preselected Slicer" Custom Visual, Pre-Selection Measure

Tags: powerbi, slicers

What should I be giving the Pre Selection field in order to have a certain value selected by default on load in my slicer?

I've tried a LOOKUPVALUE statement that yielded the matching string, and I've also tried a boolean that was only true for a specific item.
Neither of which is altering my slicer.